# Place contents of string into certain DIVs using JQUERY using identifiers within string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a "fill in the blanks" client side application using JS/JQUERY that will read in an XML file retrieved from AJAX call.

Inside the XML is a  node that contains a string with tags that identify where fields will go.

To try and improve the UI experience I am formatting the display of this form on the webpage using divs as follows

```
<div id="prologue"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="epilogue"></div>
```

I want to read through the string and use control statements to check where that part should go in those divs mentioned above.

Here is a sample string from the text node

> ${Prologue} - Dear ${Title} ${Surname}. This is a message from The Company. An person called but was unable to gain access, a new appointment has been made for ${ProductName} with order number ${VOLNumber}, on ${AppointmentDate} between ${AppointmentSlot}. Please ensure you are available at your premises for the engineer. If this is not convenient, go to thecompany.com or call 01111 1111 111 before 12:00 noon the day before your appointment. Please refer to your order confirmation for details on what will happen on the day. ${Epilogue}

Assumptions are quite simple, anything that is not ${Prologue} or ${Epilogue} goes in the **"message"** div

I have the pseudo code here

```
for loop through the string
if ${prologue} put inside prologue div tags
if !=$prologue and !=$epilogue then place in message div tag
if ${epilogue} then put inside epilogue div tags
```

There will be some other rules I will create in the loop e.g. when a "." character then insert a line break tag

The output should come to something like this

```
<div id="prologue">
${prologue}
</div>
<div id="message">
Dear ${Title} ${Surname}. <br/>
This is a message from The Company. An person called but was unable to gain access, a new appointment has been made for ${ProductName} with order number ${VOLNumber}, on ${AppointmentDate} between ${AppointmentSlot}. <br/>

Please ensure you are available at your premises for the engineer. If this is not convenient, go to thecompany.com or call 01111 1111 111 before 12:00 noon the day before your appointment. Please refer to your order confirmation for details on what will happen on the day. <br/>

</div>
<div id="epilogue">
${epilogue}
</div>
```

Could someone identify what features in javascript or jquery I could use for this implementation. I was thinking of using the .map() jquery function however I am not sure if this will work for my situation.

No full code solutions please! Just teasers so I can figure it out on my own!

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of my unformatted display

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Here's a teaser: Just use [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or another existing templating library. Why invent a new one?

Comment: Because I am getting this XML from another system outside my domain and control. The output I get from it cannot be controlled.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you modify the XML at all, I am suggesting that you map it in to HTML via a mustache template.

Comment: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/#tab-Download + https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: So the user will actually see `${prologue}`?  Or is your script removing those and placing input elements?

Comment: Thanks but I really just want to do this using Jquery or native JS . I have too many JS libraries already including a datepicker, tooltips, validation scripts etc. :)

Comment: @BenFelda ; yes I have another function that replaces those with <input> <select> or other tags depending on other rules inside the XML.

Comment: So we can spit those out based on the actual string value `${epilogue}` before you replace them correct?

Comment: Oh, wait, the prologue and epilogue are at the beginning and end.  So you don't have to do anything with them, delete them from the string and inject the input boxes directly into the div's you want.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @BenFelda see the screenshot of what my application is like at the moment, I just want to be able to have the same but neatly formatted like you would see in a letter. At the moment I am just replacing the tags with <input> tags and then appending one big string to a <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the prologue and epilogue are at the beginning and end, you don't really need to have them in your template.  So in your template engine, replace `${prologue}` and `${epilogue)}` with `""`, as you don't need them (assuming you have no control over the xml), and insert your input elements directly into the divs.

```
$('#prologue').append('<input type="text" id="prologueText"/>');
$('#epilogue').append('<input type="text" id="epilogueText"/>');
```

If you are dynamically creating the divs, you can prepend the prologue div with the prologue input, and append the epilogue div and epilogue input to a container div.  You didn't want to specific info, so I'll stop there.

So your output would be:

```
<div id="prologue">
<input type="text" id="prologueText"/>
</div>
<div id="message">
Dear ${Title} ${Surname}. <br/>
This is a message from The Company. An person called but was unable to gain access, a new appointment has been made for ${ProductName} with order number ${VOLNumber}, on ${AppointmentDate} between ${AppointmentSlot}. <br/>

Please ensure you are available at your premises for the engineer. If this is not convenient, go to thecompany.com or call 01111 1111 111 before 12:00 noon the day before your appointment. Please refer to your order confirmation for details on what will happen on the day. <br/>

</div>
<div id="epilogue">
<input type="text" id="epilogueText"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/#tab-Download and Mustache.js

Using modules with large community in most cases is better than re-inventing the wheel..

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <div id="prologue">{{{prologue}}}</div>
    <div id="message">
        Dear {{Title}} {{Surname}}. <br/>
        This is a message from The Company. An person called but was unable to gain access, a new appointment has been made for {{ProductName}} with order number {{VOLNumber}}, on {{AppointmentDate}} between {{AppointmentSlot}}. <br/>

        Please ensure you are available at your premises for the engineer. If this is not convenient, go to thecompany.com or call 01111 1111 111 before 12:00 noon the day before your appointment. Please refer to your order confirmation for details on what will happen on the day. <br/>

    </div>
    <div id="epilogue">{{{epilogue}}}</div>
</script>

$.get(YOUR_XML, function(data) {
    var json = $.xml2json(data);
    var template = $('#template').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
    $(YOUR_TARGET_ELEM).html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to use some string manipulation (to extract what you need), I expect standard JavaScript regex.

You will also need to use a jQuery [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to locate the `<div>`s on the page to update.

That should be about it, I don't see a need for a `map()` call -- you might need that later for the substitution.

Edit based on image -- You won't need `map()` after all.  Parse the string, find where to put the parts with jQuery selectors, done.